# Getting an error when trying to make a resource thread with Xenforo

Tags: php, mysql, xenforo

I've been looking for an answer and I can't seem to find it so I'm asking here.

I'm currently using Xenforo v2.2.7 patch 1 and the plugins I'm having trouble with is [XFA] RM Marketplace 4.3.4 and XenForo Resource Manager 2.2.3. When I try to make a Resource in the RM I get the following error:

```
XF\Db\Exception: MySQL statement prepare error [1054]: Unknown column 'xfa_rmmp_conf' in 'field list' in src/XF/Db/AbstractStatement.php at line 230
XF\Db\AbstractStatement->getException() in src/XF/Db/Mysqli/Statement.php at line 198
XF\Db\Mysqli\Statement->getException() in src/XF/Db/Mysqli/Statement.php at line 41
XF\Db\Mysqli\Statement->prepare() in src/XF/Db/Mysqli/Statement.php at line 56
XF\Db\Mysqli\Statement->execute() in src/XF/Db/AbstractAdapter.php at line 96
XF\Db\AbstractAdapter->query() in src/XF/Db/AbstractAdapter.php at line 220
XF\Db\AbstractAdapter->insert() in src/XF/Mvc/Entity/Entity.php at line 1512
XF\Mvc\Entity\Entity->_saveToSource() in src/XF/Mvc/Entity/Entity.php at line 1244
XF\Mvc\Entity\Entity->save() in src/XF/Mvc/FormAction.php at line 71
XF\Mvc\FormAction->XF\Mvc\{closure}() in src/XF/Mvc/FormAction.php at line 189
XF\Mvc\FormAction->run() in src/addons/XFRM/Admin/Controller/Category.php at line 138
XFRM\Admin\Controller\Category->actionSave() in src/XF/Mvc/Dispatcher.php at line 352
XF\Mvc\Dispatcher->dispatchClass() in src/XF/Mvc/Dispatcher.php at line 259
XF\Mvc\Dispatcher->dispatchFromMatch() in src/XF/Mvc/Dispatcher.php at line 115
XF\Mvc\Dispatcher->dispatchLoop() in src/XF/Mvc/Dispatcher.php at line 57
XF\Mvc\Dispatcher->run() in src/XF/App.php at line 2345
XF\App->run() in src/XF.php at line 512
XF::runApp() in admin.php at line 13
```

Everything else works and the database is not blocked or denied. I even tested a chat box plugin that uses the same database and it works perfectly fine. Does anyone have anything on how to fix this? It's not a important issue. I just want to get this resolved as efficiently as possible.

Comment: when mysql report tht the column is missing so look for xfa_rmmp_conf

Comment: Would I add it to the database it self or should change some of the coding in the MySQL php file?

Comment: that looks like an alias for an count, so it is hard to tell